# How to initialize an empty Mono Class object in reactive programming?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mono, reactive

I am learning reactive and I wanted to know how to initialize a `Mono` object, like in Java when:`User usr=new User()`.

How to create a Mono object of this similar class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways you can create an object. Checkout this link for better understanding **https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html**
Here you can just use the `Mono.just(new User());`